# How write a MySQL function which reference a field from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col_1 = a OR col_2 = a OR col_3 = a
```

I don't want to type a lot of `col_1 = a OR col_2 = a OR col_3 = a`, so I create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_col_equal(a VARCHAR(20))
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  RETURN col_1 = a or col_2 = a or col_3 = a
```

But when I execute `SELECT * FROM table WHERE is_col_equal(a)`, it gives `Unknown column 'col_1' in 'field list'`.

So, how write a MySQL function which reference a field from a table?

Comment: Why don't you just write `WHERE a IN (col_1, col_2, col_3)`?

Comment: The function doesn't know what table the query is using. The only information it gets is the parameters.

Comment: Are you trying to do this because the number of columns you wish to test can increase and you don't want to recode every time it does so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the column.  But you have to define what the function does.  If you want the function to return a value if *any* of the three columns are `a`, then you can calculate that as a value and return it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_col_equal(in_a VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    SELECT @bool = MAX(col_1 = in_a or col_2 = in_a or col_3 = in_a)
    FROM t;
    RETURN @bool
END;
```

What MySQL cannot do is return the rows that match your condition.  That does not seem to be your intention, given that you are declaring the function to return a scalar value.